# Accessing MySQL datasource bean in Spring

Tags: java, spring, jboss, jndi

I am trying to create a datasource bean for [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) from within my [Spring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework) project (in springtoolsuite), and I want to 
access the MySQL [JNDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Naming_and_Directory_Interface) (run by [JBoss application server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JBoss_application_server)).

My Bean declaration

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean" scope="singleton" >
<property name="jndiName" value="java:/MySqlDS" />
<property name="resourceRef" value="true" />
```

And from JBoss console:

```
java: Namespace
+- MySqlDS (class: org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrapperDataSource)
```

However when I ran my test application, I got the following. What have I done wrong?

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in file [/workspace-sts/test1/cspringbean.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1401)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:512)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:540)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:842)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:416)
    at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:84)
    at com.don22.EscortIdol.main(EscortIdol.java:13)
Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:645)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:288)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:325)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:154)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:178)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:95)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectLocator.lookup(JndiObjectLocator.java:105)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.lookupWithFallback(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:201)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1460)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1398)
    ... 12 more
```

Comment: This looks very like your application is not actually running inside JBoss.

Comment: That's correct, the application is NOT running inside JBoss, and I thought any application can just access JNDI resources from JBoss?

When I actually ran a web application from within JBoss, I could get the JNDI object for java:/MySqlDS fine.

So how can I access JNDI name from JBoss, if my application is just a console app NOT running in JBoss? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> javax.naming.NoInitialContextException:
>   Need to specify class name in
>   environment or system property, or as
>   an applet parameter, or in an
>   application resource file: 
>   java.naming.factory.initial

This message in the stack trace leads me to believe that either you didn't set up a JNDI data source pool in JBoss or your JNDI name is incorrect.  Check both.

UPDATE: How is your app doing the JNDI lookup with JBOSS?  If you aren't deployed in an app server, then you should be using the DriverManagerDataSource, not the JNDI data source.

Comment: I was not running my app from within JBoss, it was just a console Spring app which tried to access MySQL using JNDI running inside JBoss. Not sure if it's even possible?

Comment: How is your app doing the JNDI lookup with JBOSS?  If you aren't deployed in an app server, then you should be using the DriverManagerDataSource, not the JnidDataSource.

Comment: so I just cannot access the JNDI if I am not deployed in JBoss?
Using DriverManagerDataSource is fine, but I don't get to use the resource pool.

Comment: No, you don't.  I could be missing something here, so best to investigate how to combine something like Apache's DBCP with DriverManagerDataSource OR figure out how to use JBOSS naming service without deploying on JBOSS.  You're still stuck with having JBOSS running, so it seems to defeat the purpose.  Why are you not deploying on JBOSS?  Just curious.

Comment: Ok thanks. I was just following some Spring tutorial, which didn't mention anything about deploying into JBoss to access the JNDI names.
So maybe the next question will be "how to use JBOSS naming service without deploying on JBOSS". Anyway thanks for suggesting Apache DBCP. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would also suggest taking a look at the JEE namespace rather than defining the factory bean

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/MyDataSource"/>
```

See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/reference/xsd-config.html